# Processing triggers for man-db

Tags: 12.04

When running sudo aptitude upgrade, the console freezes for long after almost every package upgrade with a message "Processing triggers for man-db ...".  What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Ubuntu version: 12.04 (both Server and Xubuntu)

Thanks in advance.

---

Update: It looks like this problem is related to package autofs upon my further tests. Removing autofs resolved the issues. No idea why. I then have to use soft links instead of autofs for my file system to avoid this issue (and other two issues posted here as well).

Comment: I have the same problem, will see if removing `autofs` helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

The `Processing triggers for man-db` step is only executed if the file `/var/lib/man-db/auto-update` exists. This is an empty file with the sole purpose of controlling this behavior, so it can be safely removed to disable this time-consuming and arguably unnecessary process.

I personally disable this trigger on all of my systems. While the man-db cache is supposed to enhance the manual page system's speed and functionality, I have not experienced any noticeable performance degradation or functional problem after disabling the trigger.

Comment: Oh dear God why isn't this the accepted answer?  How many years of my life have I spent waiting for man-db triggers to update after packages are installed?

Comment: @Tom The reason this answer did so poorly in terms of votes is that I posted it 9 years after the question was asked and also after it had already recieved several answers that already gained lots of votes by this time. But I'm glad that at least one person stumbled upon this answer on the bottom of the page and found it useful. :)

Comment: another person :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, works great @Zoltan!

Comment: This is awesome! sudo rm /var/lib/man-db/auto-update
 Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Not building database; man-db/auto-update is not 'true'.

Answer (score 23):

***Caution:** Running the below command will remove integral parts of Ubuntu, such as the ability to read manual pages with the `man` command and related utilites such as `apropos` and `whatis`. In addition, it removes the `ubuntu-standard` metapackage, which will in turn mark an additional number of packages as manually installed. Follow this advice with extreme caution.*

Might be helpful for someone: I ran into this issue on our CI regularly.

Just execute the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge man-db
```

The command removes the man-db package completely, which in our case on CI, was completely useless anyway.

Comment: Hmm, on ubuntu this wanted to remove ubuntu-standard, which seems like a bad idea

Comment: @Kevin That is why you should never use the -y flag. I don't understand why so many people use it.

Comment: @TheRealTengri maybe it helps in a CI/CD situation as mentioned above because it's non interactive

Comment: I don't understand why this has so many upvotes. Removing the ability to read `man` pages altogether doesn't seem like a suitable solution to me. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild [Conflict of interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict_of_interest) . Depends on whether your desire to read man pages in the terminal instead of on the internet outweighs your frustration from watching some old software take longer to add a bit of text to a database than your system did to install the thing you actually asked for.

Answer (score 15):

It's possible the mandb index is corrupted.

check the index and recreate it

```
sudo mandb -t
rm -rf /var/cache/man
sudo mandb -c
```

Comment: This is the solution and works.

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to remove the cache prior to invoking `mandb` with the `-c` flag. According to the man page: ```-c, --create    By default, mandb will try to update any previously created databases. If a database does not exist, it will create it. This option forces mandb to delete previous databases and re-create them from scratch, and implies --no-purge. This may be necessary if a database becomes corrupt or if a new database storage scheme is introduced in the future.```

Comment: For me, the `-t`/`--test` action took half an hour. I’d recommend running it in tmux (or any persistent terminal), instead of plain SSH (which might be interrupted).

Comment: `rm -rf /var/cache/man` does also need a sudo....

Answer (score 6):

I had something similar just after installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux and running `update` and `upgrade`: it got stuck at `processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2)`.
And also later, after running

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

My solution: I just waited. In the second case even some 15 minutes.
I do not know whether this is normal, as I am very new to Linux. But this so people just know another experience if they run into the same problem.

Comment: The reason this is slow on WSL1 is because of slow I/O on WSL1. It is a known issue.

Answer (score 4):

The man-db update trigger is controlled by a hidden flag in debconf, which is cached on the filesystem in the path `/var/lib/man-db/auto-update`. That cached flag file is synced from the debconf database in the man-db postinst script here: https://sources.debian.org/src/man-db/2.11.2-2/debian/postinst/#L70-L79.

The right way to toggle man-db's auto-update flag is to change the value of `man-db/auto-update` to `false` in the debconf database and re-run the man-db postinst script that syncs the value to disk. Run the following commands as root:

```
echo "set man-db/auto-update false" | debconf-communicate; dpkg-reconfigure man-db
```

This flag was originally introduced to avoid rebuilding the man-db database on Debian/Ubuntu build daemons; see Debian bugs [554914](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=554914) and [579075](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=579075) for details.

Answer (score 2):

`Processing triggers for man-db` is I/O bound, and can be painfully slow if you are on a HDD, or Google Cloud's default disk storage tier.

Upgrade your disk

Comment: this is not a solution

Comment: @Habibillah i've edited my response to have a solution

Comment: I have this problem on a Raspberry Pi with a brand new SD-card.

Comment: @bomben SD cards are extremely slow

Comment: @Habibillah I actually came here because I have exactly this issue on Google Cloud, and was looking for a reason/solution

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem when I was installing apache web server on my digital ocean droplet. After waited a bit, I simply just stop the process and rerun the command. It shows the apache is already installed and it worked. 
I hope it can still help.

Answer (score -1):

Since I sometimes need the man pages.

And since there doesn't seem to be a stand-alone 'man' package, I can't simply remove 'man-db'.

My solution, for better or worse, was to move the 'mandb' executable out of the way and substitute in a copy of 'true'

On my system:

```
sudo mv /usr/bin/mandb /usr/bin/mandb-OFF
sudo cp -p /bin/true /usr/bin/mandb 
sudo rm -r /var/cache/man
```

This is easy to undo if the need arises.  And I deleted the /var/cach/man directory, as it is no longer needed and recovered megabytes of space.

Any 'man' pages you need are grabbed from the source man directory and decompressed on the fly.  No more caching means a slight inefficiency, but with today's speeder processors and disks, its minimal.

A caveat: Anytime you get a man-db package update, your modifications will be  overwritten.  Either apt-hold the 'man-db' package or be prepared to redo this at the whim of the 'man-db' package maintainers and distribution managers.

After this mod, you will still see the line "Processing triggers for man-db" fly by but it's a zero second thing. :-)

Good Luck.

Comment: Use `dpkg-divert` to move mandb executable elsewhere. Use `update-alternatives` to link /bin/true to mandb. Then you don't have to update anything after package upgrade

Comment: @midenok : Is the man-db package 'alternatives' aware?  IMHO, I don't think so.  No mention of alternative checks in its pre/post installation scripts.  It looks like any update will simply override any /dev/null or /etc/alternative links in its way.  And the 'dpkg-divert' concept tends to blow away the basic Linux KISS, do one thing and do it well principal.  I think I'll stay with just dev-nulling or 'true'ing /usr/bin/mandb

Comment: Don't do this.  man-db has a flag file to disable the automatic update.  See @Zoltan's answer.

Comment: @Tom  Following @Zoltan's answer (removing the /var/lib/man-db/auto-update flag file) will stop the auto updates to the /var/cache/man directory but appears to have no effect on the periodic cron jobs which rebuild the (useless IMHO) /var/cache/man directory. I want to get rid of the /var/cache/man directory as it is pretty useless when using a modern CPU.

Also note that just removing the /var/lib/man-db/auto-update flag file will cause the warning 

````Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Not building database; man-db/auto-update is not 'true'.````
on every apt update.